# Post login credentials and by pass login page and stay logged in

Tags: php, cookies, single-sign-on, session-cookies, php-curl

I have created a php script that POST data of username and password to a form linked to Database (mySQLI) which checks the data passed and logs in the user. when I used to enter data directly from the form it works fine. when I send through PHP-curl it by pass the login but when it redirect to the logged in page it show error stating that session variables are not initialized. Is there any way around that I can use either through session-cookies or store cookie with session id and so on?

First I tried for normal passing data and works but after adding the php-curl code it doesnt work, tried code from other questions and still same issue exist. I got the PHPSESSION ID but not sure how to utilize it to send the details to the server side to authenticate its the same user as it looks like a Single sign on system

PHP-curl file
        session_start();

```
    $cookie="C:/xampp/htdocs/cookies.txt"; 
    $url="http://localhost/login.php";    


    $postFields = array('user'=> "2001",
    "pass"=> "qw12",
    "submit" => "submit" ); 
    echo $_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"];
    session_write_close();
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);    
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postFields));
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //echo $response;

    if(!$response){
        echo "logged out";
        }

        else{
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/loginSuccess.php"); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $response; 

        }
    curl_close($ch);
```

after logged in it should redirect to this page as logged it
this is loggedin.php file where the session variables stay undefined

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>  
    <title>Log in</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    .display-4 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.2;
    }

    </style>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #E74C3C; margin:0px" >
    <div ></div>
    <span class="navbar-brand text-light" >Uni details</span>
    <br> <br>
    </div>
    <?php 

    echo $_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"];

    if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])){

    echo '<div style="width: 62%;" ></div>';
    //login  echo '<span style=" color:white; margin-right: 10px;">'.$_SESSION['uid'].'</span>';
    echo '<form  action="databaseConnection/logout.php" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-dark " style="border-radius: 5px" >logout</button>
    </form>  ';
    }
    else{
    header("Location: login.php");
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
    <!--jumbotron-->
    <?php
    if($_SESSION['uid'] == 2001)
    {

    echo '<div class="jumbotron" align="left" style="text-indent: 6.5%; background-color: transparent">
    <img src="img/aau-logo.png" style="width:10%; height:10%;" alt="aau-logo">
    <h1 class="display-4" style="text-indent:6.5%; font-weight: 500">You are logged in as: </h1>
    <div class="container" style="text-indent:0%;">
    <ul class="list-group "> 
    <li class="list-group-item" style="font-weight:500; font-size: 25px;text-align:center"> Admin </li>
    </ul>
    <br> <br>
    <button><a href="sso.php">Moodle test page</a></button>
    </div> 
    </div>';
    }
    else{
    echo '<div class="jumbotron" align="left" style="text-indent: 6.5%; background-color: transparent">
    <img src="img/aau-logo.png" style="width:10%; height:10%;" alt="aau-logo">
    <h1 class="display-4" style="text-indent:6.5%; font-weight: 500">You are logged in as: </h1>
    <div class="container" style="text-indent:0%;">
    <ul class="list-group "> 
    <li class="list-group-item "> Student ID:';?> <?php echo  $_SESSION['uid']; ?> <?php echo ' </li>
    <br>
    <li class="list-group-item "> College:';?> <?php echo  $_SESSION['col'];  ?> <?php echo '</li>
    </ul>
    </div> 
    </div>';
    }
    ?>
```

as expected it should bypass the login pass and keep me logged in until log out or browser is closed. 
just want to stay logged in throughout all the web pages in that domain.

Comment: If you want to follow redirects than you need to set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION as true (curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1))

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it still logs me out